# Write a code to add 2 rows with 100px size and 3 columns with 50px size using grid-template

Tags: css

write a CSS code using grid-template for adding 2 rows with 100px size and 3 columns with 50px size.

the code used by me ran but I need a more specific and one line code for it one using repeat function and one without using repeat function.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1):

Using repeat function:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 50px);
  gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap according to your preference */
}
```

Without using repeat function:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px;
  gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap according to your preference */
}
```